# How to prevent implicit instantiation of a template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class with several strongly typed enums and I want them to be implicitly comparable to int. For that purpose I have written super-simple template function:

```
template<class T> bool operator==(const T &e, const int &i)
{
    return (static_cast<int>(e) == i);
}
```

and the opposite one

```
template<class T> bool operator==(const int &i, const T &e)
{
    return (e == i);
}
```

However this might be dangerous because it pretty much writes a blank check for any comparison between class T and an integer. I would therefore want only few explicitly specified instantiations such as

```
template bool operator==(const MyEnum &e, const int &i);
template bool operator==(const int &i, const MyEnum &e);
```

and no other. Is there a way to disable all implicit instantiations or achieve this? I can always write both operators for each enum separately of course but templates really seem like a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Use SFINAE to reject overloads which don't deduce a `MyEnum`:</strike>

```c++
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, MyEnum>::value>* = nullptr>
bool operator==(const T &e, const int &i);

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, MyEnum>::value>* = nullptr>
bool operator==(const int &i, const T &e);
```

---

Due to the comments I have updated my answer. If you want to only accept select few template types then I suggest using this `bool_or` trick:

```c++
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<bool... Bs>
using bool_sequence = std::integer_sequence<bool, Bs...>;

template<bool... Bs>
using bool_and = std::is_same<bool_sequence<Bs...>,
                              bool_sequence<(Bs || true)...>>;

template<bool... Bs>
using bool_or = std::integral_constant<bool, !bool_and<!Bs...>::value>;

template<class T, class... Ts>
using any_same = bool_or<std::is_same<T, Ts>::value...>;

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<any_same<T, MyEnum, X, Y, Z>::value>* = nullptr>
bool operator==(const T &e, const int &i);

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<any_same<T, MyEnum, X, Y, Z>::value>* = nullptr>
bool operator==(const int &i, const T &e);
```

You can add any number of types to compare with.

Comment: Wouldn't the OP have to do this explicitly for every enum type? I thought he was looking for a solution which prevents that.

Comment: @ChristianHackl He said he only wanted for instantations that deduce `MyEnum`. Even if he wanted for every enum type that would be trivial, just use `std::is_enum<T>`

Comment: @0x499602D2: I read the question differently. To me, it seems he has a few enum types and wants some easy solution to provide the operators only for them and no other types, enum or not (which IMO is an impossible requirement). After all, if he only wanted it for `MyEnum`, then what would be the point of templates?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I see, then he would have to write some type traits and `enable_if` on those traits.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks for the answer. I think both could work and in my situation (4 enums so far) they would be around the same amount of code. However I am really intrigued by your updated solution and I think I even understand it now. :-) However when trying it out I am getting template declaration of 'bool any_same' 'any_same' was not declared in this scope template argument 1 is invalid error on the template of the operator==... I tried modifying the code but to no avail, any ideas?

Comment: @Resurrection Yeah that's  new feature called variable templates. See the update.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ah yes, works like a charm now. :-) I noticed that any_same is missing 'using' but it complained about not having a typename before bool_or when I tried to add it but I see now it was due to extra ::value. Thanks again!